# Unable to connect hivellap from pyspark

Tags: pyspark, jupyterhub, spark2

I am using pyspark kernel inside jupyterhub and want to connect hivellap from spark . I am able to create a spark session but when i am trying to execute 
 from pyspark_llap import HiveWarehouseSession it is showing error no module found pyspark_llap

The same command i am able to execute in python kernel and it successfully executed.

Kindly suggest what configuration is needed to import HiveWarehouseSession from pyspark_llap inside pyspark kernel.